# How to get original positions of items in an intersection?

Tags: c++, intersection

I have two vectors containing integers, I can get an intersection of those vectors, but that only gives me the values, I also want to know the index positions/keys of the original items. How can I do this? I have tried to use `lower_bound` to search each vector for the items in the intersection to find their positions, but that is slow. I'm hoping there is some clever way to perhaps use a custom comparator or something like that in `set_intersection` to gain access to the keys of each item being compared, but I've not had any luck searching for a way to do that.

Comment: You should show how you get the values of the intersection. It is likely that very few modifications are needed to get the indices.

Comment: Make a struct with index + value and make vectors of that. Write your own algorithm that returns those indexes there are a lot of ways to do it.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider writing your own `set_intersection`-like function which returns a set of index pairs instead?

Comment: set_intersection works with sorted sequence... Are your vectors sorted ? Do they contain unique integers ?

Comment: Do the two vectors have the same size ? Are they completely random ?

Comment: can you provide a  simple example of what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer would go to [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude). Good idea.

I found a `set_intersection` implementation in the cppreference.com C++ documentation. I've made a few modifications to do what he suggested, and it gives great results.

Here is example code that shows how it works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template<class Value, class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt my_intersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                         InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                         OutputIt d_first)
{
    auto start1 = first1;
    auto start2 = first2;

    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (*first1 < *first2) {
            first1++;
            continue;
        }

        if (*first2 == *first1) {
            pair<Value, vector<size_t>> item;
            vector<size_t> positions;

            positions.push_back (distance (start1, first1));
            positions.push_back (distance (start2, first2));

            item.first = *first1;
            item.second = positions;

            *d_first++ = item;

            *first1++;
        }

        first2++;
    }

    return d_first;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    vector<int> v2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 30, 50, 70, 90, 100, 1000 };

    vector<pair<int, vector<size_t>>> intersection;

    my_intersection<int> (
        v1.begin (), v1.end (),
        v2.begin (), v2.end (),
        back_inserter (intersection)
    );

    for (auto &item : intersection) {
        cout << item.first << ":";

        for (auto &position : item.second) {
            cout << " " << position;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2: 1 0
4: 3 1
6: 5 2
8: 7 3
```

Comment: It's a minor style thing, but may I suggest `if (*first1 < *first2) { ++first1; continue; }` then moving the rest of that loop body out of the `else` clause, removing a level of indentation?

Comment: That makes sense. It is done.

Comment: @Coffee'dUpHacker: A heads up: When working with what might be class objects (which most iterator-like things will be), you *always* want to use prefix increment (Chris's suggestion correctly used it, you flipped it), even if it means a one-liner splits to two lines. Postfix increment on a non-primitive type involves a copy (because it must return a copy of the original value by value, while modifying the reference to the original object), which prefix increment avoids (modifying in place and returning a cheap reference).